# Where does `mv file.sh /~` move the file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mv

I moved a file with

```
mv file.sh /~
```

So I moved the file from the current directory to `/~`. However I have not idea what/where `/~` is.

Comment: to find it out, you could just enter `cd /~`. And you will see that `~` is pointing to the home directory.

Comment: @Chris623 … or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` has a special meaning only at the start of a word. Therefore, `/~` is a file named `~` located in the topmost root directory.

Normal user shouldn't be able to create files in the `/` directory. Be double careful when running with admin privileges and don't run commands you don't understand.